# What is the best approach to use after user has made a payment?

Tags: forms, payment

After a user has finished paying for an item, what is the best thing to show them right after they are finished?

I was thinking of showing an order status page with a receipt that would show whether the purchase was successful or if it failed to be processed, is this normally the standard? Is it necessary to make this an entire page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show them the order status page, thank them for their purchase and send them the receipt or purchase order via email. Whether you want to make this an entire page or pop up is up to your design. You could also throw in some product recommendation based on their current purchase.

Comment: Pop ups don't work very well on mobile

Comment: @Jake I disagree. It's not hard to make it work. For mobile you can simply set the pop-up to a full-width, absolutely positioned div with a higher z-index.  Using 320 as a minimum width, this works great.

Comment: I agree with @BramVanroy you could redo a bootstrap modal at 100% VIEWPORT width and height